# Discord Bot on_member_join

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help with a discord Bot,

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('new member')
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Unnamend')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(str(member.roles))
```

this is my code and if I join I didnt get a message or a role did some one know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Intents are missing.

Make sure to turn on all the necessary ones in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**To implement them to your code you can use the following:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)
```

***Or in your case:***

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```