# How To Make The Bot Say The Amount Of Online And Offline People In Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So, what I'm trying to do is make the bot send the amount of offline and online people.

```
@bot.command()
async def members(message):
  id = bot.get_guild(server token here)
  await message.channel.send(f'Total-Members: {id.member_count}')
```

This only lets the bot say the amount of total members without any further specification. Can you please help me? I want the bot to say the total members, the offline members, the online members, and the bots.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370231/how-to-get-a-number-of-online-members There is also a very useful link to the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter members with their statuses.

```
@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    total = len(ctx.guild.members)
    online = len(list(filter(lambda m: str(m.status) == "online", ctx.guild.members)))
    idle = len(list(filter(lambda m: str(m.status) == "idle", ctx.guild.members)))
    dnd = len(list(filter(lambda m: str(m.status) == "dnd", ctx.guild.members)))
    offline = len(list(filter(lambda m: str(m.status) == "offline", ctx.guild.members)))
    humans = len(list(filter(lambda m: not m.bot, ctx.guild.members)))
    bots = len(list(filter(lambda m: m.bot, ctx.guild.members)))
    await ctx.send(f"Total: {total}\nHumans: {humans}\nBots: {bots}\nOnline: {online}\nIdle: {idle}\nDo not Distrub: {dnd}\nOffline: {offline}")
```

---

---

Also command object takes `commands.Context` not `message`.

Comment: when i try this, it works, but it says

Total: 1
Humans: 0
Bots: 1
Online: 0
Idle: 0
Do not Distrub: 0
Offline: 1

which is not the correct amount of people. i did exactly what u did

Comment: Did you enabled intents? If you don't you need to enable it in developer portal.  Then define bot like this in your code: `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())`

Comment: Also don't ask a question multiple times and don't mention about me like `last time someone has said`.

Comment: im sorry, i will make sure not to mention people like that

Comment: now it say raise `PriveligedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None` as an error

Comment: @Coder999 Enable intents. An answer I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994217/discord-bot-on-member-join/66994329#66994329

Comment: it was working, i needed to go into the discord developer portal and change the bot settings.